# requests are taken to the wrong directory

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, xampp

I use xampp on windows 7 64, to test locally my php web application

I use virtual hosts to have access to my code from different domain names.

Now, I created a new version  of the code and want to access both versions using different domain names.

I added a  new virtual host newversion.mysite.local to httpd-vhosts.conf and directed it to the directory of the new version. 
Also updated the windows hosts file with the line 127.0.0.4 newversion.mysite.local

A strange thing happens: when browsing to newversion.mysite.local I'm being taken to the *old* version, which is located at a different location.

How the hell this happens?
Please help me with ideas

Thank you

Gidi

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but Apache answers using the first vhost entry it finds. I'd double check that you vhost entries actually use the different hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

As pst said, I bet it's serving the first virtual host configuration. Did you test your configuration with `apachectl -S` ? This will output what virtual hosts are being loaded. My money's on a misconfigured [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost).

Verify you have

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.4
```

in your httpd.conf before the virtual host configurations.